# O que é computação nas nuvens?

Tags: cloud

Eu nunca entendi direito onde fica a fronteira que determina se uma aplicação é na "nuvem" ou não.

Exemplos:

- Uma das primeiras aplicações que surgiram totalmente online são os e-mails, como hoje temos o Gmail, Outlook, etc, acessível totalmente via *browser*. Nunca vi ninguém chamar isso de "nuvem", mas será que não seria o caso, já que isso funciona sem que seja necessário instalar nada na máquina?
- Se um dono de empresa resolve liberar o acesso externo ao ERP em seu servidor, para que algumas pessoas possam acessar de suas casas, isso já se caracteriza como nuvem? Se não, o que seria necessário para isso ser uma "nuvem", colocar isso em um servidor de terceiros?
- Um site simples, como um *blog*, poderia ser considerado uma mini aplicação nas nuvens?

Qual é a fronteira que determina se algo é "nas nuvens" ou não? O que é computação nas nuvens?

Comment: A fronteira é... nublada. Em parte, "nuvem" é um termo de marketing (buzzword).

Comment: Eu acho que [isso aqui](http://www.google.com/loon/) poderia ser considerado computação nas nuvens... :P

Comment: @bfavaretto `"A fronteira é... nublada."` Have an internet, good sir.

Comment: A fronteira desta pergunta também é nublada :) Raspa o *off-topic*. Quase ninguém sabe ao certo o que significa o termo que tem pouca relevância. Tem empresas que vendem *cloud* porque tá na moda, mas ele nem sabem o que estão vendendo e não é nem de longe *cloud*. Esta é uma das piores palavras já criadas na indústria já que ela não ajuda entender o mecanismo, é usada indiscriminadamente para algo se assemelha a tecnologias existentes há anos ou décadas e ajuda vender algo questionável como panacéia. O artigo da Wikipedia é um bom começo mas não pare nele. Qualquer informação resumida vai...

Comment: atrapalhar mais que ajudar. Não conheço o livro mas http://books.google.com.br/books?id=SbSbdkqibwIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false é um recurso que pode ajudar, ele pelo menos parece tentar fugir do marketing que é usado em várias publicações.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O termo "computação em nuvem" [originalmente se referia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/cloud_computing.html) a uma arquitetura de rede onde vários computadores - não necessariamente idênticos, ou de igual capacidade - colaboram na realização de uma determinada tarefa. Sendo que novos computadores podem ser livremente introduzidos no conjunto, ou retirados dele, sem a necessidade de se parar o processamento e/ou reconfigurar tudo.

Hoje em dia ele é mais usado no contexto de [Software como Serviço (SaaS)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o)*, onde você não realiza a computação no(s) seu(s) computador(es), mas sim contrata alguém para hospedar os sistemas necessários - pagando só pelo poder de processamento, espaço em disco, conexões de rede... E fiel à filosofia da nuvem, permitindo-se aumentar ou diminuir o tamanho do contrato (i.e. quanto você paga, e quanto recurso está alocado para você) de forma facilitada.

> *Ou, como [apontado por Caputo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30308/215), outros tipos de serviço, mas mantendo a característica de não "engessar" o sistema ao ambiente sendo executado.

Colocando isso no contexto da sua pergunta:

- Tanto os serviços de webmail quanto outras aplicações cliente-servidor (ex.: o Viaweb - depois Yahoo! Store - primeira aplicação web da história) não são considerados "nuvem" porque não há essa característica do escalonamento: o provedor oferece um serviço fixo e pouco customizável, e uma determinada quantidade de recursos, e só. Às vezes há planos diferentes (ex.: 1GB de espaço de e-mails, 5GB, etc) mas é raro ver algo "sob-demanda" (onde você paga mais ou menos, mês a mês, conforme sua previsão de necessidade).
- O exemplo do ERP é semelhante - o serviço é fixo, as condições são determinadas pelo dono da empresa... Transferir para um servidor de terceiros, por si só, não muda nada (digamos que você contratou um [Servidor Virtual Privado - VPS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPS) - a um custo fixo com recursos fixos - isso não caracteriza a computação em nuvem). O que pode ocorrer é que esse provedor de terceiros ofereça a hospedagem com características da computação em nuvem (você escolhe quanto espaço vai precisar e quanta transferência mensal, paga proporcionalmente, um pouco a mais se exceder o limite, etc).
- De novo, o site não seria um exemplo de nuvem. Mas se o site estiver hospedado num servidor que cobra proporcionalmente ao tráfego de rede utilizado, ou ao espaço em disco utilizado para as postagens do blog/comentários, aí seria um serviço em nuvem.

Conforme [comentário do bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30302/o-que-%C3%A9-computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nas-nuvens#comment56550_30302), não há um critério simples pra dizer se algo é "na nuvem" ou não. Hoje em dia essa expressão é muito usada como sinônimo de "na web". Mas eu diria que, se o serviço não permite aumentar ou diminuir a alocação de recursos **sem mexer nas configurações** [do ponto de vista do cliente, o contratante], eu não chamaria isso de "nuvem" - ainda que seja descrito como tal (e não esquentaria a cabeça com isso, afinal um nome é só um nome...).

**Adendo:** na minha resposta me referi sempre a "um serviço que você contrata", mas na realidade não é necessário um contrato com terceiros pra uma plataforma ser considerada "nuvem": você pode ter uma empresa com infra-estrutura própria (servidores, co-locados ou hospedados nas suas próprias dependências) que organiza e disponibiliza seus recursos computacionais na forma de nuvem. Sendo que os diversos sistemas instalados na rede interna, os diversos departamentos da empresa, etc, tenham recursos alocados a eles de forma dinâmica, e não estática (o servidor X hospeda a aplicação A, o Y as aplicações B e C, etc; vamos implantar o serviço D? precisamos comprar mais um servidor... etc). É o que chamaríamos de "nuvem privada" ([*private cloud*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Private_cloud)).

Comment: Eu não diria que os serviços de WebMail não são considerados "nuvem" pelo simples fato de oferecerem um serviço fixo, porque não é o serviço que ele oferece que faz dele ser ou não um programa que roda na nuvem e sim a implementação dele. É totalmente possível um serviço de webmail ser desenvolvido para nuvem, mas ele não necessariamente precisa ser.

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa Concordo! Você pode oferecer um serviço SaaS tradicional implementado numa arquitetura em nuvem. Apenas digo que do ponto de vista do cliente aquilo não é um serviço em nuvem. De todo modo, vem de novo aquela questão da fronteira nebulosa...

Answer (score 6):

### Segundo o [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)

> Cloud Computing é a entrega de computação como serviço ao invés de
>   como produto, pelos quais recursos compatilhados, software e
>   informações são fornecidas aos computadores e outros dispositivos como
>   um utilitário (como a rede elétrica) através de uma rede (geralmente a
>   Internet) Nuvens podem ser classificadas como públicas, privadas ou
>   híbridas.

Portanto CloudComputing não é o produto entregue mas a disponibilização de serviços através de uma rede.

Estes modelos de serviços podem ser *(segundo o mesmo artigo da Wikipedia)*:

### Infraestrtutura como um serviço *(Infrastructure as a service (IaaS))*

Provedores de Iaas oferecem computadores (físicos ou máquinas virtuais) e outros recursos, load balance, fail over, habilidade de escalar serviços a mais ou a menos dependendo da demanda ou necessidade dos clientes, armazenamento com backups distribuidos, VLAN, firewalls.

### Plataforma como serviço *(Platform as a service (PaaS))*

No modelo PaaS, os provedores de cloud entregar uma plataforma de computação que geralmente inclui o SO e um ambiente de execução de uma linguagem de programação, bancos de dados e servidores Web. Com este modelo, desenvolvedores podem entregar suas aplicações sem ter de se preocupar com as camadas de Hardware e software e focar apenas em desenvolver os seus produtos.

Como exemplo temos Microsoft Azure, Google App Engine, que escalam processamento e armazenamento sem necessitar de intervenção manual do desenvolvedor.

### Software como Serviço *(Software as a service (SaaS))*

Neste modelo de negóciom usuários têm acesso a aplicações e seus bancos de dados. Provedores de cloud fornecem a IaaS e a PaaS que rodam a aplicação. SaaS geralmente são considerados "software sob demanda" pois são pagos por uso.

No modelo SaaS os provedores instalam e gerenciam as aplicações e os usuários dos software acessam seus serviços e pagam por período ou por consumo.

### Sendo assim:

> Uma das primeiras aplicações que surgiram totalmente online são os
>   e-mails, como hoje temos o Gmail, Outlook, etc, acessível totalmente
>   via browser. Nunca vi ninguém chamar isso de "nuvem", mas será que não
>   seria o caso, já que isso funciona sem que seja necessário instalar
>   nada na máquina?

Instalar não é o ponto determinante, o email pode ser considerado um SaaS e sim, seria um Cloud pois é uma aplicação vendida para você utilizar, sob a responsabilidade de outra empresa

> Se um dono de empresa resolve liberar o acesso externo ao ERP em seu
>   servidor, para que algumas pessoas possam acessar de suas casas, isso
>   já se caracteriza como nuvem? Se não, o que seria necessário para isso
>   ser uma "nuvem", colocar isso em um servidor de terceiros?

Não, seria núvem se o negócia dessa empresa fosse o ERP e ele vendesse o acesso a ele para outras empresas.

> Um site simples, como um blog, poderia ser considerado uma mini aplicação nas nuvens?

Não, pois ele não fornece nenhum serviço a seus usuários

Answer (score 2):

Em seus exemplos, considero-os como `serviços` e cada prestador de serviço escolhe como entregá-los ( em qual datacenter hospedará, como fará o software, etc...)

Já a `computação na nuvem` é quando **você roda sua aplicação num computador que você contratou como serviço** e nem o vê.

Mas apenas esta descrição não caracteriza cloud, pois você precisa que este serviço que está dando suporte a `sua` aplicação suporte algumas propriedades, como a escala sob demanda ou serviços agregados como firewall, roteadores, novos discos,
banda contratada ajustável.

Considero o melhor exemplo atual de Cloud Computing os serviços separados que são oferecidos pela [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/)