# Qual a diferença de computação nas nuvens e computação web?

Tags: aplicação-web, terminologia, cloud

Qual a diferença de **computação nas nuvens** e **computação web**?

Ambas não são locais e são majoritariamente acessíveis via *browser* então tem-se a impressão que são conceitos semelhantes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não vou me aprofundar, até porque os termos são usados de forma muito, eu diria, aleatória.

Tem uma [pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30302/101) explicando o que é computação em nuvem e pincela sobre web.

## Web

A computação web é aquela que trabalha em cima do protocolo HTTP. Isso pode ocorrer de várias formas. O servidor pode estar em nuvem, ou não. Eventualmente pode até mesmo o cliente estar na nuvem, embora altamente incomum e não sei se faz sentido fazer isto.

## Nuvem

A computação em nuvem não exige protocolos específicos, só precisa atender alguns critérios expostos na pergunta *linkada*. O fato de ser acessível por web é um acaso, é algo possível, eventual. Para a nuvem não importa.

## Local

É preciso definir melhor o que significa "local", mas é um erro afirmar que ambas não são locais. Em geral as pessoas usam remotamente (outro local físico), mas podem ser locais sim, e é mais comum do que parece. Mesmo que local signifique rodar no mesmo computador, ainda assim pode-se dizer que ser local é uma possibilidade.

## Termo

O termo nuvem hoje é usado como instrumento de marketing mais do que de engenharia. As pessoas falam sobre nuvem quando não passa nem perto disso. Algumas pessoas consideram que se é web, é nuvem. Alguns consideram até o modelo de cobrança como definidor se é nuvem, ou seja, se cobrar pelo uso e não um valor fixo, é nuvem.

## Utilidade

Na verdade poucas organizações precisam de nuvem de fato.

- Elas precisam de web.
- Precisam de ter uma centralização.
- De estar remoto.
- Elas precisam de virtualização, mesmo localmente.
- Precisam de boa organização dos recursos e facilidades de implantação e manutenção.

Em alguns casos talvez até podem usar tecnologias usadas pelas nuvens, mas sem a característica típica de escalonamento da nuvem.

## Custo X benefício

Nuvem de verdade costuma sair muito caro (mas vendem como se fosse mais barato) e tira um pouco da flexibilidade do que se pode fazer. Ela tem vantagens, mas pode sair mais barato em nichos ou quando compara com algo mal feito.

Mesmo o aluguel de uma virtualização costuma sair mais caro, mas há casos que é mais interessante, assim como a nuvem pelo tipo de utilização que ela terá.

Só tirar a estrutura de dentro da empresa e passar para terceiros sem agregar nenhum valor real é só má gestão de recursos feita porque alguém que vai na moda por falta de conhecimento do que está fazendo.

## Exemplo

Por isso este site aqui não usa nuvem. Quando tem engenheiros de verdade trabalhando não caem em armadilhas de mercado.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um servidor que essencialmente é usado para servir web. Oficialmente ele está na nuvem, mas minha contratação não é como nuvem de fato. É uma instância virtual, sai relativamente barato. Como a utilização é baixíssima e no Brasil os custos de comunicação de dados são absurdos, acaba compensando. Se esses custos específicos fossem mais baixos eu teria, mesmo algo pequeno, aqui comigo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).