# Mas afinal o que é um SaaS?

Tags: terminologia, saas

Estava a ler esta pergunta [O que é computação nas nuvens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30302/7210) e fiquei na dúvida de qual a linha que separa um software dito normal de um [Software como Serviço (SaaS)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_como_servi%C3%A7o).

Afinal o que é um SaaS? E quais as principais diferenças para um software dito normal?

Comment: Quando bati o olho na pergunta eu li sass , enfim, ótima pergunta, estarei acompanhando, também tenho essa dúvida

Comment: Não confundir com [tag:sass]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As duas características fundamentais que diferenciam um "[Software as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)" ou sob demanda, de um software normal, também chamado de *on premisse*, são:

- ele é centralizado em algum lugar, normalmente uma nuvem pública, mas não necessariamente.
- o pagamento é feito de acordo com o uso, ou um valor periódico ou por unidade de consumo, tais como tempo, operações, valores movimentados (números de funcionários, certificados emitidos, etc.), ou qualquer outra fórmula que faça sentido.

Em geral você "compra" mais que o software, compra a infraestrutura e um suporte completo ao que precisa. Não precisa se preocupar com o hardware, rede (até certo ponto), *backup*, manutenção, *upgrade* da estrutura, *update* de versões, etc.

Nem sempre isto é verdade. Há casos em que apenas o modelo de pagamento mensal ou algo assim já caracteriza um SaaS. Mas há quem discorde destes casos.

Em tese é um "pague para usar". Pague de acordo com a demanda e isso tornaria os custos menores. Na prática é comum os custos serem maiores no longo prazo, mas depende um pouco de uma série de fatores.

É comum em softwares para web, mas nada impede o uso de outras formas. É comum precisar de um cliente, mobile ou desktop para acessar o software principal.

Muitos vezes há ganhos por haver um compartilhamento dos recursos usados (até mesmo pessoas) entre todos os usuários. Mas há um custo em tentar fazer tudo funcionar bem, para todo mundo, no mesmo ambiente. Pode ser até mais complicado ou cobrar um custo de falta de flexibilidade oferecida.

Há quem reclame da falta de controle, segurança e comodidade. Não é fácil identificar o quanto é uma boa solução.

Também vende-se a ideia de que é mais previsível assim. Na prática sempre que o fornecedor tem custos adicionais, não previstos, ele acaba repassando para o cliente. O que pode acontecer é ter menos custos imprevistos pela experiência do fornecedor, mas isso não é garantido. Dependendo do modelo adotado o custo pode ser muito menos previsível. E quando é previsível acaba cobrando pelo máximo que gastaria, pelo pior caso, o que não é vantagem alguma.

Esta é uma forma de melhorar o faturamento da indústria, tanto que depois dela, explodiu o faturamento de muitas empresas do setor, desde fornecedores de nuvem, quanto dos produtos que antes eram vendidos sem esse modelo, incluindo softwares básicos e específicos. Se a indústria está faturando tanto mais então não ofereceram menos custos como o prometido. Isso ocorreu justamente quando o modelo atual (antigo agora) de cobrança estava mostrando saturação. Algumas pessoas dirão que está se vendendo mais software que antes. Não vi evidências claras que seja isso.

É uma forma da indústria combater a pirataria.

Enfim, tem vantagens, mas também traz desvantagens e não vou listar todas porque nem é o foco da pergunta.

Ele tem irmãos: [IaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Infrastructure_as_a_service_.28IaaS.29), [PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service), [DaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Desktop_as_a_Service), [MBaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service), entre outros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando você diz que ele tem irmãos como o PaaS seria o mesmo que dizer que eles tem objetivos iguais mas fazem isso de forma diferente?

Comment: Na verdade não, pelo menos do meu ponto de vista. São modelos parecidos com objetivos diferentes, ou seja, você centraliza em algum lugar e paga conforme usa por um serviço completo, mas o que está sendo oferecido é outra coisa, é uma plataforma, uma infraestrutura geral, é um desktop, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Utilizando o Azure como exemplo,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima tenta ilustrar um pouco a diferença entre cada uma das modalidades de nuvem disponíveis *no Azure*.

- **IaaS - Infrastructure as a Service:** O provedor disponibiliza toda a
  infraestrutura para configuração ao usuário. Este tem acesso a
  máquinas virtuais e servidores para serem configurados, permitindo um
  controle maior sobre o ambiente disponível. Para a publicação de um website, por exemplo, o usuário deve configurar o servidor de aplicação, as portas de acesso, o firewall, etc.
- **PaaS - Platform as a Service:** O provedor disponibiliza um modelo onde
  a infraestrutura é abstraída, e o usuário precisa se preocupar apenas
  com a configuração da plataforma. Este modelo possui certas limitações, mas torna sua configuração muito mais fácil e ágil de ser realizada, pois o usuário não precisa se preocupar com a infraestrutura necessária para executar a aplicação. Para a publicação de um website, por exemplo, é necessário apenas que você crie um PaaS com as configurações necessárias para executar seu site, e publica-lo através de FTP, por exemplo.
- **SaaS - Software as a Service:** O provedor disponibiliza tanto o hardware (Infrastructure) quanto o software (Platform) como um serviço. O usuário acessa diretamente o software aqui, sem ter a necessidade de realizar configurações técnicas para isto. Temos como exemplos aqui o Office 365, calendarios e serviços de e-mail.

> E quais as principais diferenças para um software dito normal?

Quando falamos de SaaS e falamos de núvem, é importante que o software obedeça às características que definem uma tecnologia de núvem. Esta é a principal diferença entre um *software as a service* e um *software dito normal*.

A titulo de informação, segue abaixo [algumas características consideradas essenciais para que uma tecnologia seja considerada cloud](http://www.inforisktoday.com/5-essential-characteristics-cloud-computing-a-4189).

- **On-demand self-service:** O usuário deve ter a capacidade de provisionar recursos para a núvem sem a necessidade de interação humana para isto.
- **Broad network access:** Basicamente, o provedor deve disponibilizar o serviço de forma que seja possível acessa-lo através da internet.
- **Rapid elasticity:** O provedor deve disponibilizar ao consumidor a possibilidade de aumentar ou diminuir os seus recursos de forma rápida em determinados cenários. Você pode pensar na elasticidade como uma feature para que o usuário não gaste recursos de forma desnecessária, consequentemente pagando mais por isto. Um website de compras pode utilizar o serviço de rápida elasticidade durante uma promoção, como a black friday, por exemplo.
- **Measured Services:** O provedor deve disponibilizar uma forma de mensurar os recursos utilizados pelo serviço, para que seja possível monitora-lo e controla-lo, construindo assim uma melhor transparência entre o consumidor e o provedor.